# Using CASE to set a condition for COUNT statement in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, case

I have a SELECT statement in SQLite where I need to find the amount of vehicles registered per person in the past year. This is the query:

```
SELECT
p.fname,
p.lname,
p.bdate,
p.bplace,
COUNT(
  DISTINCT CASE r.vin WHEN r.regdate >= date('now', '-1 years') THEN 1 ELSE null END
),
COUNT(DISTINCT(t.violation))
FROM
persons p
LEFT JOIN registrations r ON p.fname = r.fname
AND p.lname = r.lname
LEFT JOIN tickets t ON r.regno = t.regno
GROUP BY
p.fname,
p.lname,
p.bdate,
p.bplace;
```

The problem is with the CASE statement, it is not detecting when the condition is true and defaults all my values to 0. How can I fix this, or are there other ways to spcecify a condition in a COUNT statement

Comment: Try changing the `ELSE null` to `ELSE 0`.

Comment: @daShier No that doesn't work because then the count statement counts the 0 as a value and adds up the unwanted rows too, it needs to be null so COUNT doesn't count it

Comment: It's comparing `r.vin` against the result of `r.regdate >= date('now', '-1 years')` which seems unlikely to be what you want or work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you want this:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN r.regdate >= date('now', '-1 years') THEN r.vin END)
```

because `COUNT(DISTINCT 1)` does not make sense.
`ELSE null` is not needed.

Comment: I had to add a DISTINCT in front of this to get the result that I needed, but thanks! I knew that my case format was wrong, I was combining what I read on different stackoverflow forums, but yea this works, thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`FILTER`](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#aggfilter)(SQLite 3.30.0):

```
SELECT
   p.fname, p.lname, p.bdate, p.bplace,
   COUNT(DISTINCT r.vin) FILTER (WHERE r.regdate >= date('now', '-1 years')),
   COUNT(DISTINCT(t.violation))
FROM persons p
LEFT JOIN registrations r ON p.fname = r.fname
  AND p.lname = r.lname
LEFT JOIN tickets t ON r.regno = t.regno
GROUP BY p.fname, p.lname, p.bdate,p.bplace;
```

Comment: Cool.  I didn't realize SQLite supported `filter`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, they added support FILTER for aggregates recently(2019-10-04)

Comment: Probably should mention that that requires the released-a-week-ago sqlite 3.30 to work.